# Easier way to do multiple loop styled actions?

Tags: php

I'm reasonably new with AJAX but have had some good help, both on reading up and asking specific questions on here. This one is for the php backend...

I have a load of code like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['shortTitle'])) {
    $userInput = ucwords($_POST['shortTitle']);
    if(trim($userInput) == "") { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_$applicationKey SET `shortTitle` = :userinput, `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_STR, 64);
        $stmt->bindParam(':time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
    $report_shortTitle = array();
    if($userInput == NULL) {
        $report_shortTitle['errorText_shortTitle'] = "This field cannot be left blank";
        $report_shortTitle['resultImg_shortTitle'] = "<img src=\"./gfx/form_boo.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10008;\" title=\"&#10008;\">";
    } else {
        $report_shortTitle['errorText_shortTitle'] = NULL;
        $report_shortTitle['resultImg_shortTitle'] = "<img src=\"./gfx/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">";
    }
    echo json_encode($report_shortTitle);
}

// groupName
if(isset($_POST['groupName'])) {
    $userInput = ucwords($_POST['groupName']);
    if(trim($userInput) == "") { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_$applicationKey SET `groupName` = :userinput, `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_STR, 64);
        $stmt->bindParam(':time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
    $report_groupName = array();
    if($userInput == NULL) {
        $report_groupName['errorText_groupName'] = "This field cannot be left blank";
        $report_groupName['resultImg_groupName'] = "<img src=\"./gfx/form_boo.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10008;\" title=\"&#10008;\">";
    } else {
        $report_groupName['errorText_groupName'] = NULL;
        $report_groupName['resultImg_groupName'] = "<img src=\"./gfx/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">";
    }
    echo json_encode($report_groupName);
}
```

Which all works, however it would be nice if I could simply use one blob of code for everything that is actioned in the same style - the data post from the input fields all the way through to the DB insertion are always consistent - is shortTitle, groupName etc. Obviously the

```
$stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_STR, 64);
```

line will be different so I guess I'll need different pieces of code, for "PDO::PARAM_STR, 64", PDO::PARAM_INT, 11" etc but that is ok. How can I work it so that I only need one bit of code. I'm sure it must be possible, but I am unsure how to achieve this. Feedback appreciated!

Comment: Quick tip: if `lastmodified` is defined as `TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the table structure, you can get rid of that entire concern from your PHP code.

Comment: Anyway, let me introduce you to this very useful feature called [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php).

Comment: Hi Niet, I'm using the lastmodified within the php because if I just use the mysql stamp it'll give me the local server time, not the relevant users time. The site is hosted in a different timezone to the target audience, so I've implemented php's date_default_timezone_set to emply the relative correct timestamp.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` columns do not use timezones. The timezone is applied to the result you get when you `SELECT` it, according to the current timezone (set in MySQL!) and means you can change timezones without having to re-convert all of your data.

Comment: Hmmm ok, so what would you recommend I do to change my code to take up your suggestion here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use array for dependable parts and use a foreach.

$names = ['groupName', 'shortTitle'];

```
foreach($names as $name){

  if(isset($_POST[$name])) {
    $userInput = ucwords($_POST[$name]);
    if(trim($userInput) == "") { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_$applicationKey SET '$name' = :userinput, `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");
      $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_STR, 64);
      $stmt->bindParam(':time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
      $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
      $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
    $report_name = array();
    if($userInput == NULL) {
      $report_name['errorText_'.$name] = "This field cannot be left blank";
      $report_name['resultImg_'.$name] = "<img src=\"./gfx/form_boo.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10008;\" title=\"&#10008;\">";
    } else {
      $report_name['errorText_'.$name] = NULL;
      $report_name['resultImg_'.$name] = "<img src=\"./gfx/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">";
    }
    echo json_encode($report_name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mr.nm - that works perfectly. Little exhausting having to create the different array's of data for each item (there is a lot of numerical data involved) but this does speed things up a lot! :)

Comment: Interestingly for some reason this does not work on the production server... :(

Comment: you can change this line     

$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_$applicationKey SET '$name' = :userinput, `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");

with

$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_$applicationKey SET '".$name."' = :userinput, `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");

sometime variables in string may not be executed.

Comment: It was a good idea but has not changed the result. Still failing on the live server.